# Linear Regression Loops in R

Tags: r

I need beta coefficients and residual variance for multiple stock. My question is, how can I create a loop for multiple linear regression and extract the aforementioned coefficients into the output?

Here is what my data looks like, MR is my independent variable and rest of the columns are dependent variables, to each of which I have to perform a linear regression separately.

[image: Dataset]

Thank you very much!

//Edit:

```
> dput(head(Beta_market_model_test))
structure(list(...1 = structure(c(1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 
1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), R1 = c(-0.0225553678146582, 0.084773882172773, -0.00628335525823254, 
0.189767902403849, -0.129765571642446, -0.02268699227135), R2 = c(-0.000634819869861802, 
0.0566396021070485, 0.0504313735522286, -0.0275926732076482, 
0.0473125483284236, -0.0501700832780339), R3 = c(-0.0607564272876455, 
0.0915928283206455, -0.116429377153136, 0.0338313435925748, -0.0731748018356279, 
-0.082292041771696), R4 = c(0.036716647443291, 0.0409790469126645, 
-0.0594941218382615, 0.0477272727272728, 0.0115690527838033, 
-0.0187634024303074), R5 = c(0.00286365940192601, 0.0128875748616479, 
0.000174637626924046, 0.0238214018458469, 0.0120599342185406, 
-0.0627587867116033), R6 = c(-0.0944601447872712, 0.090838356632893, 
-0.0577132600192821, 0.136928528648433, -0.0137770071043408, 
0.0214549609033041), MR = c(-0.0388483879770769, 0.0858362570727453, 
-0.0178553084990147, 0.0567646974926548, -0.0391124787432181, 
-0.014626289866472)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It would be so helpful if you could share a reproducible piece of your data.

Comment: I added data into the question, is it useful or should I try something else?

Answer (score 4):

We could use `cbind` to specify the dependent variables in `lm`

```
model <- lm(cbind(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6) ~ MR, data = df1)
s1 <- summary(model)
```

NOTE: We assume that the 'R1' to 'R6' are numeric columns i.e. the `,` should be replaced with `.` while reading into `R`

#### Update

If there are many columns and are in the range of sequece, extract those columns and convert to `matrix`

```
dep_data <- as.matrix(Beta_market_model_test[startsWith(
                 names(Beta_market_model_test), "R")])
model <- lm(dep_data ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)
```

Checking the `summary`

```
summary(model)
Response R1 :

Call:
lm(formula = R1 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
 0.03757 -0.06851  0.01791  0.08624 -0.06919 -0.00402 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 0.006368   0.028060   0.227   0.8316  
MR          1.711625   0.577571   2.963   0.0414 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.06831 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6871,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6088 
F-statistic: 8.782 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.04141


Response R2 :

Call:
lm(formula = R2 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.01047  0.03882  0.03925 -0.04355  0.03750 -0.06155 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.01232    0.02079   0.593    0.585
MR           0.06402    0.42797   0.150    0.888

Residual standard error: 0.05062 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.005564,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.243 
F-statistic: 0.02238 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.8883


Response R3 :

Call:
lm(formula = R3 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 0.035081  0.014541 -0.049701 -0.002909  0.023029 -0.020041 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.04197    0.01431  -2.934  0.04266 * 
MR           1.38661    0.29449   4.709  0.00925 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03483 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8472,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8089 
F-statistic: 22.17 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.009249


Response R4 :

Call:
lm(formula = R4 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 0.0438966  0.0002996 -0.0603723  0.0182067  0.0188503 -0.0208810 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.007732   0.016804    0.46    0.669
MR          0.383843   0.345886    1.11    0.329

Residual standard error: 0.04091 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2354,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.04425 
F-statistic: 1.232 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.3293


Response R5 :

Call:
lm(formula = R5 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 0.013692 -0.001676  0.006728  0.015178  0.022942 -0.056863 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.002917   0.013351  -0.218    0.838
MR           0.203653   0.274801   0.741    0.500

Residual standard error: 0.0325 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1207,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.09909 
F-statistic: 0.5492 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.4998


Response R6 :

Call:
lm(formula = R6 ~ MR, data = Beta_market_model_test)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.04498 -0.03837 -0.03832  0.04938  0.03608  0.03622 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 0.006197   0.020555   0.302   0.7781  
MR          1.433135   0.423083   3.387   0.0276 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05004 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7415,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6769 
F-statistic: 11.47 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.0276
```

---

We could get the summary output in a data.frame easily in a tabular format with `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(summary(model), tidy, .id = 'dep_var')
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   dep_var   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#   <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Response R1 (Intercept)  0.00637    0.0281     0.227 0.832  
# 2 Response R1 MR           1.71       0.578      2.96  0.0414 
# 3 Response R2 (Intercept)  0.0123     0.0208     0.593 0.585  
# 4 Response R2 MR           0.0640     0.428      0.150 0.888  
# 5 Response R3 (Intercept) -0.0420     0.0143    -2.93  0.0427 
# 6 Response R3 MR           1.39       0.294      4.71  0.00925
# 7 Response R4 (Intercept)  0.00773    0.0168     0.460 0.669  
# 8 Response R4 MR           0.384      0.346      1.11  0.329  
# 9 Response R5 (Intercept) -0.00292    0.0134    -0.218 0.838  
#10 Response R5 MR           0.204      0.275      0.741 0.500  
#11 Response R6 (Intercept)  0.00620    0.0206     0.302 0.778  
#12 Response R6 MR           1.43       0.423      3.39  0.0276
```

Or to get other output with `glance`

```
map_dfr(summary(model), glance, .id = 'dep_var')
```

Comment: I should have specified it in my first post, but I actually have about 800 columns of data and specifying each one would take too much time. Thank you very much for your suggestion regardless!

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there any way to get the beta coefficients and residual variances for each stock (R1, R2, R3, etc.) in a list or table?

Comment: Dear akrun, when I have a data frame like this I normally use pivot to have all the independent variables in one column so that I can nest them beside dependent variable. Do you think this way of handling the problem is a bit verbose? I mean does it in your opinion involve a some unnecessary steps?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR you can use that as well.  Here, I make use of the `lm` functionality that can take multiple dependent variables as a matrix

Comment: @AnoushiravanR only issue with that pivoting is when you have a really big data and and the pivoting could increase the rows to a degree that it would exceed the limitations

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. It sounds great. By the way is it possible to iterate over every independent variable the way `across` function does without the need to pivot them?

Comment: Thank you Akrun! Sorry to still bother you, but is there another way to go from column to column, as in reality all the columns do not start with "R"?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR  You can use `Beta_market_model_test %>% select(-1) %>% summarise(across(-MR,  ~ list(lm(reformulate('MR', response = cur_column()), data = Beta_market_model_test) %>% summary))) %>% unclass %>% map_dfr(~ tidy(.x[[1]]))`

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I wouldn't have imagined to use `reformulate` in my wildest dreams. Thank you for answering my questions. It's always a pleasure discussing these matters with you.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR you could also update that in your post as it may help somebody else (very few people read the comments)

Comment: @akrun I did, thank you very much for this valuable recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just posting this to ask a question about my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

df %>%
  select(-...1) %>%
  pivot_longer(R1:R6) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest(data = c(MR, value)) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(MR ~ value, data = .)), 
         glance = map(model, ~ glance(.x))) %>%
  unnest(glance) %>% 
  select(- c(data, model))

# A tibble: 6 x 13
# Groups:   name [6]
  name  r.squared adj.r.squared  sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance
  <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 R1      0.687          0.609  0.0331    8.78   0.0414      1  13.2  -20.3 -20.9  0.00438
2 R2      0.00556       -0.243  0.0590    0.0224 0.888       1   9.69 -13.4 -14.0  0.0139 
3 R3      0.847          0.809  0.0231   22.2    0.00925     1  15.3  -24.6 -25.2  0.00214
4 R4      0.235          0.0443 0.0517    1.23   0.329       1  10.5  -15.0 -15.6  0.0107 
5 R5      0.121         -0.0991 0.0555    0.549  0.500       1  10.1  -14.1 -14.7  0.0123 
6 R6      0.742          0.677  0.0301   11.5    0.0276      1  13.7  -21.5 -22.1  0.00362
# ... with 2 more variables: df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

**Update**

Thanks to my dear friend @akrun who always provides me with valuable suggestions.

In case you would like to avoid pivoting the data as with a really big data the pivoting could increase the rows to a degree that it would exceed the limitations, you can use the following code as well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

df %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  summarise(across(-MR, ~ list(lm(reformulate('MR', response = cur_column()), 
                                   data = df) %>% 
                                  summary))) %>% 
  unclass %>% 
  map_dfr(~ tidy(.x[[1]]))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)  0.00637    0.0281     0.227 0.832  
 2 MR           1.71       0.578      2.96  0.0414 
 3 (Intercept)  0.0123     0.0208     0.593 0.585  
 4 MR           0.0640     0.428      0.150 0.888  
 5 (Intercept) -0.0420     0.0143    -2.93  0.0427 
 6 MR           1.39       0.294      4.71  0.00925
 7 (Intercept)  0.00773    0.0168     0.460 0.669  
 8 MR           0.384      0.346      1.11  0.329  
 9 (Intercept) -0.00292    0.0134    -0.218 0.838  
10 MR           0.204      0.275      0.741 0.500  
11 (Intercept)  0.00620    0.0206     0.302 0.778  
12 MR           1.43       0.423      3.39  0.0276
```